# Having Trouble Checking If User Already Logged In With Their Facebook Account

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-studio, facebook-login

I have been able to successfully implement the Facebook login button. My only problem now is I'm having trouble checking if the user already logged in.

This is code for when the user clicks the login button:

```
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    getFacebookData(object);
                }
            });

            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "name, email, picture");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

        }
    });
```

`getFacebookData` has this code:

```
private void getFacebookData(JSONObject object) {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Profile.class);
        String fb_name = object.getString("name");
        String fb_email = object.getString("email");
        URL profile_picture = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/" + object.getString("id") + "/picture?type=large");
        intent.putExtra("name", fb_name);
        intent.putExtra("email", fb_email);
        intent.putExtra("profile_picture", profile_picture.toString());
        intent.putExtra("userOption", 2);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Basically, when the user logs in successfully, it sends the user's name, email, and profile picture data to the `Profile` activity.

Now, what I have in my `onCreate` method inside my `MainActivity` class is:

```
AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
boolean isLoggedIn = accessToken != null && !accessToken.isExpired();
if (isLoggedIn) {

}
```

This above code checks to see if the user has already logged in with their Facebook account. What I want to put inside the if statement is `getFacebookData()` because this will send data to the `Profile` activity and start the `Profile` activity immediately instead of going to the `MainActivity`. My problem is, I have to pass in a `JSONObject`.

What should I do to fix this as I don't know what `JSONObject` to pass into the `getFacebookData()` function?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can store the user name, email and id permanently in you application (e.g. shared preferences).

To insert:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("fbId", fbId);
editor.putString("fbEmail", fbEmail);
editor.putString("fbName", fbName);
editor.commit();
```

To retrieve:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String fbId= sharedPref.getString("fbId");
String fbEmail = sharedPref.getString("fbEmail");
String fbName= sharedPref.getString("fbName");
```

If you really want to request those again, you can use following method:

```
AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
boolean isLoggedIn = accessToken != null && !accessToken.isExpired();
if (isLoggedIn) {
       GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), 
            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    getFacebookData(object);
                }
        });

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "name, email, picture");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
}
```